# jQuery .animate() not doing anything in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate, opacity

I have a `div` of text (`#text-write`), each character of which is `span`ned. The `div` is `absolute`ly `position`ed inside a `relative`ly `position`ed container `div` (`#typetext`). Here's the effect intended:

1. Animate inner `div` (`#text-write`) to `opacity 0` for 400ms.
2. Animate each `span` inside inner `div` one after the other to `opacity 1` for 400ms each.
3. Pause for 5 seconds.
4. Go back to 1.

I simply can't make this work in IE8. It works in IE7 and below, IE9, other major and obscure (that i know of) browsers. I've been pulling my hair trying out everything I found on the net (add layout to the `absolute`ly `position`ed inner `div`, play with `filter`, try fade, etc.) for the last 5 or so hours.

The logic is running (I tried inserting an `alert` in the recursive call, and IE8 does the `alert` for each `span`ned letter and in the exact timing, even the pause), no errors in console, either.

But nothing is happening to the `opacity`. It does not even disappear. It just stays there.

Can you help?

```
        jQuery(function() {
            // span each letter in text
            var textType = jQuery('#text-write').remove().text(), textTypeLength = textType.length,
                fadeSpeed = 400, fadePause = 5000,
                textSpanned = '';
            for (i=0;i<textTypeLength;i++) textSpanned += '<span>' + textType.charAt(i).replace(' ','&nbsp;') + '<\/span>';
            jQuery('#typetext').append('<div id="text-write">'+ textSpanned + '<\/div>');

            // fade phrase logic
            function fadeType(){
                var letters = jQuery('#text-write span').animate({opacity: 0}, fadeSpeed),
                    i=0;
                (function(){
                    jQuery(letters[i++]).animate({opacity: 1}, fadeSpeed, arguments.callee);
                })();
            }

            // make it happen
            fadeType();
            setInterval(function(){fadeType();},fadePause + fadeSpeed + (textTypeLength*fadeSpeed));

        });
```

Comment: Try using filter: alpha(opacity=70); in ie 8

Comment: thanks, kim, but i already tried that and it doesn't work. :/ any other thoughts? thanks

Comment: Can you get a working version up on jsbin or jsfiddle or somewhere?

Comment: hi graphicdivine! sorry, just saw this. fin'lly found the solution and posted it below. thanks anyways, really 'preciate it. have a gooder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer over at http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/#dsq-cite-119679059

the `<span>` elements i wanted to animate were of course inline. `display`ing them as `inline-block` finally did it for ie8. thanks much jeko, who found the solution over at http://www.devcomments.com/IE-8-fadeTo-problem-with-inline-elements-to65024.htm

posting here for anyone else out there who may need it and not waste as much time as i had.

Comment: Changing `display: block;` to `display: inline-block` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, I was using animate to move items around with percentages. IE does not support percents. I switched animate from percentages to pixels and it worked just fine.