# animate color web icon font doesn't work on IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm confused about this problem.
I wanna animate color of an icon font, it works fine in all modern browsers, but not in IE 8!

We have a link:

```
<a id="newsletter_subbut"><i class="icon-web-mail"></i></a>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
#newsletter_subbut {
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width:40px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    font-size:22px;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:9px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.icon-web-mail:before {
    font-family: 'batch';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: "\F14C";
}
```

and this is my jQuery code:

```
$('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").stop().animate({color: "#fa2a18"},'slow');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526251/resolved-jquery-animate-not-doing-anything-in-ie8

Answer (score 1):

IE8 can't animate the color because the browser can't animate the color on its own. You need a script that will do the work for IE8.

@Hadi added a custom color animation script, that's small and light.

I prefer Jquery UI because it will do the trick for you. it's added in my jsfiddle. (see framework and extensions). http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/667kF/6/

```
$('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").stop().animate({color: "#fa2a18"},'slow');
```

Update: you're adding the icon with

```
i:before { content: \F14C"; }
```

The Jquery is animating the actual i  of the content :before. But googling its seems that animating pseudo classes isnt supported yet.

http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/

There is a solution, but that's only suited for the modern browsers.

Solution for you is to add the unicode in the html. see my http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/667kF/8/

Comment: Did our answers work out for you ? Could you vote for our answers ? Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately no! but thx.
as i said,this problem is on icon web font.it works fine with normal text

Comment: PLING! Offcourse it doesn't work. See post update for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of jquery you are using. Anyway, animate color doesn't work for 1.9.1, may work in earlier version. Sometimes IE8 doesn't understand the animate property. You can try like this -

```
$('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").stop().animate({color: "#fa2a18"}, 1000, function(){ $('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").animate({ color: "#fa2a18" }); });
```

or

```
$('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").animate({ color: "#000" }); // your original color
$('#newsletter_subbut').find("i").animate({ color: "#fa2a18" });
```

i know this is crazy. But it works for me.

and if you are using jquery 1.9.x then - try this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HETuE/ - it works in ie8 as well

Comment: thx dude, i use jquery 1.9.1 and this plugin http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/
it works great even in ie8, but just when i user normal text instead of icon web font

Comment: can you please fiddle it, as i can see it live?

Comment: hi dudes,
i search more and unfortunately find out that IE 8 doesn't support transition and animate color for :before and :after content.
Thx a lot for replies.